# find comma in oracle sql string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my oracle db as character and data stored in this is like here

```
30.170527093355002,72.615875338654 and
30.805165,71.82474
```

Now I want to get the separated by comma whole string. I mean I want to get the part of string before comma and also part after comma separately. Please any one tell me is there any built in function to do this that I can separate my while string by comma regardless of comma position where it exist.I have already tried floor function and substr but all in vain please help me to use any built in function or user defined function to full fill my requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    select
      substr( COLNAME, 1, instr( COLNAME, ',') - 1 ) as p_1 ,
      substr( COLNAME, instr( COLNAME, ',', - 1 ) + 1 ) as p_2
    from YOURTABLE
```